# SpannerIO Batch Read Speed Affected by Slow Partition Reader

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-spanner

We have been using `SpannerIO.readAll` to scan large amount of data in google dataflow setting. The `ReadOperation`s passed to spanner are created `withQuery(query)` and `withBatching(true)`. I noticed that though initially the throughput is OK, it dropped to very low throughput in the end probably due to outliers with larger amount work. Looking at [BatchSpannerRead](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/spanner/BatchSpannerRead.java) code, one DoFn is taking care of all the batch scan work for a partition. Although in a perfect world, we should assume the generated partitions should handle this outlier issues, but in practice, will it make sense to re-split the work of those slow workers?

Comment: What does the "Monitor" page in the Cloud Spanner instance being used show? (this is on the Google Cloud Console web UI) What is the CPU utilization? It may be that you need more Nodes? It may be that your query is inefficient (have you run the query in the web UI and looked at the query execution plan to see if say a Table Scan is triggered)?

Comment: The utilization is very low, I used 5 nodes, and the util was like 10% at most. The query is simple and it is basically prefix scan with the first primary key set to some value.

Comment: To understand this a deeper investigation needs to be carried out. Looks like it would be better if you would open a ticket with support for this case. If you do not have a paid support package or your trial period has expired, I would ask you to create an issue on a public issue tracker. I will then make it public.